# Excel VBA to clear filters from table and supress any errors

Tags: vba

Go easy im a newbie, and new to Excel and VBA etc.

I have a large database that contains user profile details which is in table form. the issue i am having is i have a command button to clear the filters that are applied to the table, i got the requried macro by recording it, however if there are no filters applied i run into the below error:

Run-time error '1004':

ShowAllData method of worksheet class failed

I know why im getting the error, which is simply because there are no filters applied and hence it throws this error up, what i would like is to have this error ignored entirely.

Here is my Command Button code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()
ClearFilters2 Macro
Range("Table24[#Headers]").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Any help to supress the runtime error would be appreciated, could i ask that the code be supplied with the correction?

Thanks,

JD

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` will enable your code to completely ignore errors - although typically it's not advised to use. `On Error GoTo 0` will allow errors to occur once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `On Error Resume Next`.

You should ensure to turn error handling back on at a suitable place in your code `On Error GoTo 0`.

You can also create a label and tell the code to go to this label if an error occurs `On Error GoTo <label>`.

See [Chip Pearson's article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) on error handling for more information.

Comment: Can you provide examples on how i would include the above?

Comment: Just put `On Error Resume Next` at the top of the procedure. So after line `Private Sub CommandButton25_Click()`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much indeed.